# How to sort big xml list with no unique field/element to sort by

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sorting

I have a really big xml to sort, i am trying to validate that there are no differences between two XML lists but all my "Diff" applications show a lot of differences even though i know 98% of the information is in both lists.

i have tried some various ways of sorting the XML by one or multiple elements, so that they are ordered the same way but with no luck because both the xml's doesn't have a unique value for each "Row" so to speak. There is an Email field but sometimes the email tag is missing completely, which doesn't make it a good field to sort by.

looks something like this:

```
<Customer>
  <row CompanyID="1" Name="John" Email="John@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="1" Name="Jane" Email="Jane@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="1" Name="Howard" Email="Howard@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="2" Name="Jen" Email="Jen@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="2" Name="James" Email="James@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="3" Name="Phil" Email="Phil@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="3" Name="Kenny" \>
  <row CompanyID="3" Name="Andrew" Email="Andrew@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="3" Name="Greg" Email="Greg@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="4" Name="Julia" Email="Julia@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="4" Name="Hannah" Email="Hannah@mail.com" \>
  <row CompanyID="4" Name="Riley" Email="" \>
  <row CompanyID="4" Name="Anders" Email="Anders@mail.com" \>
</Customer>
```

(XML only for showing purpose)

Is there any good ways to solve this problem?

what i need is either a good way of sorting both of them or a comparing application that has the technology to compare xml's not taking object order to account so to speak.

Comment: For each element in A try to find an equal element in B. Shouldnt be the hardest task to do.

Comment: Not hard to do, but doing that for 50k rows took my computer well over 1,5 hour and even then i had to cancel the procedure :P

Comment: Then you might wanna ask for improvments on your algorithim. This can definetly be improved alot.

Comment: Hens the question, i'm not looking for an improvement, i'm looking for a best practice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft XML Diff https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

```
public void GenerateDiffGram(string originalFile, string finalFile, XmlWriter diffGramWriter)
{
   XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
       XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces | XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);

   bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(originalFile, finalFile, false, diffGramWriter);
   diffgramWriter.Close();
}
```

The Compare() method returns true if the two files are identical, and false otherwise.
The last argument, diffgramWriter, is where the output of the comparison is written. The output generated is an XML document that records the differences between the two files. Here is what it looks like in this scenario:

```
public void CompareXml(string file1, string file2, string diffFileNameWithPath)
        {

            XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(file1));
            XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(file2));

            StringBuilder differenceStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(diffFileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                XmlWriter diffGramWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fs);

                XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
                                        XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                                        XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
                bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(file1, file2, false, diffGramWriter);

                diffGramWriter.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any way to show this sort the files in stead of just returning a true of false. A true or false doesn't cut it, i need to make it visible somehow.

The files are in a constant changing state so i need to somehow make the compassion visible. Thank you for the quick answer though :)

Comment: Another way would be if Microsoft XML Diff would sort and then the program could save the file. then i could use one of the comparison applications to show the differences in a visible state.

Comment: The Compare() method returns true if the two files are identical, and false otherwise. The last argument, diffgramWriter, is where the output of the comparison is written. The output generated is an XML document that records the differences between the two files. check the example above

Comment: did it work for you? i only get: "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long." It crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom Xml sorter that may help :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SortXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XmlSort xmlSort = new XmlSort();
            xmlSort.SortXml(doc);
            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class XmlSort : IComparer<XElement>
    {
        public void SortXml(XDocument doc)
        {
            RecursiveSort(doc.Root);
        }
        public void RecursiveSort(XElement elements)
        {
            foreach (XElement element in elements.Elements())
            {
                RecursiveSort(element);
            }
            List<XElement> children = elements.Elements().AsEnumerable().ToList();

            if (children.Count > 1)
            {
                children.Sort(new XmlSort());
                elements.ReplaceWith(new XElement(elements.Name.LocalName, children));
            }
        }

        public int Compare(XElement a, XElement b)
        {


            string attributesA = string.Join("^", a.Attributes().Select(x => string.Join("^",x.Name.LocalName + (string)x))); 
            string hashA = string.Join("^", new string[] {a.Name.LocalName, attributesA, (string)(XElement)a.NextNode});

            string attributesB = string.Join("^", b.Attributes().Select(x => string.Join("^", x.Name.LocalName + (string)x)));
            string hashB = string.Join("^", new string[] { b.Name.LocalName, attributesB, (string)(XElement)b.NextNode });

            int results = hashA.CompareTo(hashB);
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works somewhat but not completely, it still misplaces about 5k rows  and the first 100 that i looked att manually (that are misplaced that is) are all exactly the same but not inte the same order. @jdweng

Comment: sorry maybe i totally miss understood the last comment but, each issue? i'm only inserting one file at a time. The single file is containing 50k rows each. 
is that what you ment? @jdweng

Comment: Sorry.  It looks like I posted wrong comment.  Deleted it.  Are you sorting both xml files and then  comparing?

Comment: Yes, i am sorting the first one, after that one has finished and saved to a file, i do the next one, then i try comparing them using DiffMerge application, and it shows about 5k differences.

Comment: Need some help to find out what is wrong.  I'm comparing the tag name, attribute name, attribute value, and innertext.   The only thing I'm not doing is sorting the attributes by name.  Did you turn off option in compare to ignore unimportant items like spaces.  I usually use Beyond Compare.

Comment: Sorry @jdweng, i may be pretty unfamiliar here, and i'm really trying to learn but i'm really not following here haha :(

Comment: Post example of elements not sorting properly so I can modify code or explain issue.