# Comparing 2 Xml files with pure c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a strange "assignment" I have to do for an interview and I've ran out of ideas and resources. I need to write a program similar to the XML Diff and Patch Tool example to find the differences between 2 xml files, but without using said resource. I have to output the differences, count the differences, and display the original xml files in one form, functionality is all that is required. I currently have code that can do all but the comparing and counting and have hit a wall. Here is my current code without the third compare button,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = " xml|*.xml";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            filebox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (filebox1.Text != null)
            {
                XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
                doc1.Load(filename: filebox1.Text);
                foreach (XmlNode node in doc1.DocumentElement)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(child.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = " xml|*.xml";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            filebox2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (filebox2.Text != null)
            {
                XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
                doc2.Load(filebox2.Text);
                foreach (XmlNode node in doc2.DocumentElement)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(child.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

No xml is shows due to this needing to be able to work with any 2 xml files with any kind of content. Any suggestions? Much thanks.

Comment: If this is for an interview it is quite bad to ask other people to tell you how to do it. It’s ok to ask for help in specific parts but now you’re basically asking how to do the whole task. If you cannot do this task why do you think you should pass the interview?

Comment: Since order doesn't make a difference with xml are you allowed to sort the xml?  I did a xml sort at following posting that may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537733/how-to-sort-big-xml-list-with-no-unique-field-element-to-sort-by/46540113#46540113,  Once the xml is sorted you could join xml at each level.